# Deno Simple Static CRUD Example

Tags: node.js, deno

It [appears](https://github.com/manyuanrong/deno_mysql/issues/16) that the current mysql driver for Deno does not yet support password authentication. I have just finished an API in PHP and would like to see an example of the same in Deno.

This is as much as you get as far as an example from their site:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.58.0/http/server.ts";
const s = serve({ port: 8000 });
console.log("http://localhost:8000/");
for await (const req of s) {
  req.respond({ body: "Hello World\n" });
}
```

Where do I add JSON headers on this?

Is the router native or does it have to be something called OAK?

Is it possible you could add a static GET, POST, PUT DELETE to this example returning post.json, get.json, put.json, delete.json file contents at each respective end point?

I'm just having a hard time finding examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the router native or does it have to be something called OAK?

No, there's no built-in router. You can use Oak or other HTTP framework.

---

To return a file, you use `Deno.open` which returns a `Reader`, and you can pass that `Reader` to `body` property of `req.respond`, which accepts a `Reader`, `string` or `Uint8Array`.

The following example will read the file `{HTTP_METHOD}.json`, and return its content, setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

```js
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.58.0/http/server.ts";
const s = serve({ port: 8000 });
console.log("http://localhost:8000/");

async function handleRequest(req) {
  try {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const file = await Deno.open(`./${req.method.toLowerCase()}.json`);
    await req.respond({ body: file, headers })
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    req.respond({ body: 'Internal Server Errror', status: 500 });
  }
}

for await (const req of s) {
  handleRequest(req);
}
```

The std HTTP server is a bit low level, you probably want to use a Framework.

- https://github.com/oakserver/oak
- https://drash.land/docs/#/

Frameworks have plenty of examples.

Comment: Marcos, this is a great start! Ok. When using `Deno.open`, is `./` referring to `deno.exe` default location? Basically, what's my root directory in Deno?

Comment: Getting error ` TS7006 [ERROR]: Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.
async function handleRequest(req) {`

Comment: I gave a JS example, if you're using typescript, set the correct type: `ServerRequest`

Comment: Where do I set the correct type? Just for this example. Oak Docs are looking great.

Comment: `async function handleRequest(req: ServerRequest) {`

Comment: ` TS2304 [ERROR]: Cannot find name 'ServerRequest'.
async function handleRequest(req:ServerRequest) {`

Comment: You have to export the class `import { serve, ServerRequest } from "https://deno.land/std@0.58.0/http/server.ts";`